# How to add tabs inside navigation drawer, design error or fragment error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, navigation-drawer

How to add a tab inside the Navigation Drawer ? I getting error when I try to add a tabs inside navigation drawer. 
Navigation Drawer:

```
public class MyFitTrackNavActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_fit_track_nav);

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new HomeFragment()).commit();


            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_fit_track_nav, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            int id = item.getItemId();

            switch (id) {
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new SettingFragment()).commit();
                    return true;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_home)
            {
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new HomeFragment()).commit();
            }
            else if (id == R.id.nav_weight)
            {
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_tab, new WeightFragment()).commit();
            }

            else if (id == R.id.nav_logout)
            {
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new LogoutFragment()).commit();
            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            item.setChecked(true);
            setTitle(item.getTitle());
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Tabs:

```
public class WeightFragment extends Fragment {

    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 3 ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_control, container, false);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));


        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new KeyInWeightF();
                case 1 : return new HistoryF();
                case 2 : return new AnalysisF();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }    
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Weight";
                case 1 :
                    return "History";
                case 2 :
                    return "Analysis";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

this is onr of the tab fragment in the tab (WeightFragment)

```
public class KeyInWeightF extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.daily_weight_fragement,null);
    }
}
```

this is my tab design :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.sam.myfittrack.Tabs.WeightFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tablayout"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                          at com.example.sam.myfittrack.MyFitTrackNavActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MyFitTrackNavActivity.java:118)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:150)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
                                                                          at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:300)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4336)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17826)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5434)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: fallow this helps you out - http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: that is a tabs, i need create a tabs inside navigation drawer.When i click on an item in navigation drawer ,  it will show the tabs

Comment: you want to create tabs inside your fragment ? follow this link clearly http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/material-design-tabs-with-fragments  , First check your fragment loading when you click on nav tabs  properly if its loading start creating tab over your fragment

Comment: i try follow the link you gv me 
but if you got some sample code is good for me, cause now i have 2 project, 1st project i create the nav drawer, 2nd i create tab in activity with 3 fragment, now i want combine the tab project in the nav but nav is using fragment, so i getting stuck

Comment: see use same app  compact in both classes which you are using